# How to check if a string contains any element of a list & get the value of the element?

Tags: javascript, string, list, search, contains

I want to determine if a string from a list 'websites' is contained in another string 'url' & get the value of the string from the list as well.

The code below can determine if a string from 'websites' can be found within 'url', but fails to get back which string from the list triggered .some().

I get the following error: "ReferenceError: website is not defined"

Is there any way to get the value of the string from 'websites' after finding that 'url' contains some value of 'websites'?

```
websites = [
'google',
'youtube',
'twitter',
]

var url = window.location.href  // e.g. returns www.google.com/soooomethingelse

if (websites.some(website => url.includes(website)))
{
   console.log(website)  // here I want to log 'google' from 'websites'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a lot easier would be to just use `.find` method, which returns the element when the condition in the arrow function is met (arrow function returns `true`).

```js
websites = [
  'google',
  'youtube',
  'twitter',
]

var url = window.location.href // e.g. returns www.google.com/soooomethingelse

var website = websites.find((el) => url.includes(el))
if (website) {
  console.log(website) // here I want to log 'google' from 'websites'
}
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!